# Socket Programming Python - Multi Thread

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm building a multi-thread server in Python and for some reason I cannot connect two or more clients, so I was going to ask if there is possible that two clients with the **same IP ADDRESS** and the **same PORT NUMBER** can be connected to the same server?

Comment: Two clients with the same ip address on the same network leads to collisions. How would a computer (or a routing device) know to what client they need to send a packet? Because this breaks on a network level, it won’t work on the application level.

Comment: Can you provide an minimal working example?